# Docker as a Server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, iptables, portforwarding, ports

Im trying expose various docker containers to the outside world from a local machine. Im exposing ports 7050, 7051 and 7053. The problem is when I curl from another machine I get a partial response followed by "connection reset by peer". How can I solve this?

My iptables look like this:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Thu Nov  9 15:52:53 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [116:7924]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:100]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:478]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [12:1018]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/16 ! -o br-07afd2287e48 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.128.6/32 -d 172.20.128.6/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7050 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.128.4/32 -d 172.20.128.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7053 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.128.4/32 -d 172.20.128.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7051 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i br-07afd2287e48 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i br-07afd2287e48 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7050 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.128.6:7050
-A DOCKER ! -i br-07afd2287e48 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7053 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.128.4:7053
-A DOCKER ! -i br-07afd2287e48 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7051 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.128.4:7051
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov  9 15:52:53 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Thu Nov  9 15:52:53 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [313:21234]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [219:157256]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o br-07afd2287e48 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-07afd2287e48 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-07afd2287e48 ! -o br-07afd2287e48 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-07afd2287e48 -o br-07afd2287e48 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.20.128.6/32 ! -i br-07afd2287e48 -o br-07afd2287e48 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7050 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.20.128.4/32 ! -i br-07afd2287e48 -o br-07afd2287e48 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7053 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.20.128.4/32 ! -i br-07afd2287e48 -o br-07afd2287e48 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7051 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i docker0 -o br-07afd2287e48 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i br-07afd2287e48 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
```

This are the same rules I use on a AWS EC2 instance and works like charm

Also I configured my modem to assign my MAC address a static IP which is: 192.168.1.121

Port forwarding looks like:

[image]

Lastly docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
          ip_range: 172.28.5.0/24

services:
  ca.peers.aabo.tech:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$ARCH-1.0.3
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.peers.aabo.tech
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.peers.aabo.tech-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/a64f36ae49c527e08b9b3a97443006a9668d288a8bdcd2ca1e11a5f40ccf114e_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    expose:
      - "7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/peers.aabo.tech/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.peers.aabo.tech
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.2

  orderer.aabo.tech:
    container_name: orderer.aabo.tech
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$ARCH-1.0.3
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    expose:
      - "7050"
    volumes:
        - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/aabo.tech/orderers/orderer.aabo.tech:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/peers.aabo.tech/peers/peer0.peers.aabo.tech/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerPeers
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.3

  lyra1.peers.aabo.tech:
    container_name: lyra1.peers.aabo.tech
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$ARCH-1.0.3
    environment:
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=lyra1.peers.aabo.tech
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=lyra1.peers.aabo.tech:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=PeersMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=lyra1.peers.aabo.tech:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=composer_default
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start -o orderer.aabo.tech:7050
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    expose:
      - "7053"
      - "7051"
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/peers.aabo.tech/peers/peer0.peers.aabo.tech/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/peers.aabo.tech/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
    depends_on:
      - orderer.aabo.tech
      - couchdb
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.4

  cli.aabo.tech:
    container_name: cli.aabo.tech
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli.aabo.tech
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=lyra1.peers.aabo.tech:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=PeersMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/peers.aabo.tech/users/Admin@peers.aabo.tech/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/sacc
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - /home/frhec/go/src/:/opt/gopath/src/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    depends_on:
      - orderer.aabo.tech
      - couchdb
      - lyra1.peers.aabo.tech
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.5

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:$ARCH-1.0.3
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    expose:
      - "5984"
    environment:
      DB_URL: http://localhost:5984/member_db
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.6
```

I'm using ArchLinux Antergos

```
Linux INSPIRON-HFR 4.13.11-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 2 10:25:56 CET 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

-----EDIT 1-----------------

Currently I'm getting:

```
$ curl WAN_IP:7050
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer ��
```

I expect:

```
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

By the way. If a curl from localhost I get the expected response.

Thanks

Comment: Partial response means you get some actual output you expect? What part of the HTTP request comes back?

Comment: It really hard to tell. I expect binary output so when I curl I get:                curl WAN IP:7051
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer ��

Comment: I expect:                                                                                         Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.

Comment: Is there HTTPS there? Did you try `openssl s_client -connect WAN_IP:7050`?

Comment: Nop, I just tried and got:                                         CONNECTED(00000003)

139666957153944:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 305 bytes